# mv: missing destination file operand

Tags: command-line, mv

I am trying to install poweriso, but facing this error. I had successfully extracted the poweriso on the desktop,and found the following code as instruction for further installation-

```
sudo mv -v /home/abiggj/Desktop/poweriso/usr/bin/poweriso
```

but it still hasn't worked.

Comment: I guess you should put a psace before  '/usr...` Besides, it is helpfull in such a case to get the full text of what happens when you enter the command (error message, for instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing space, the correct would be.

```
sudo mv -v /home/abiggj/Desktop/poweriso /usr/bin/poweriso
```

Notice the space after `/home/abiggj/Desktop/poweriso`.

Comment: 'mv: cannot stat '/home/abiggj/Desktop/poweriso': No such file or directory'- I get this when I tried the code you suggested.

Comment: It means you don't have `poweriso` file on your `~/Desktop` directory, are you sure its there?

Comment: Sorry, my bad it was named as "poweriso-x64", but still there is a problem when I run the corrected code. The terminal copies everything, and then removes the complete directory, still the program doesn't get installed.

Comment: Try `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/poweriso-x64`.

Comment: sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/poweriso' did run but performed nothing.

Comment: `chmod +x` made your file executable. You are now able to run it with `/usr/bin/poweriso-x64`

Comment: '/usr/bin/poweriso' says - "bash: /usr/bin/poweriso: Is a directory".

Comment: Try `ls /usr/bin/poweriso`

Comment: Gave a long list.

Comment: @ANIKETJHARIYA The executable file is inside that folder, please post output to your main post by [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1148210/edit)ing it.

Comment: @ANIKETJHARIYA please [edit] your question and add the output of all of these commands. That way, we can understand what the current situation is and we don't need to pull it out of you step by step in the comments.